# How would I Get User Online or Offline Using Timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I Have this code I would like to use to get Online or Offline status for use of a profile page. I can not seem to get the correct information. It shows as Online all the time, Or if i use `<` in it, it comes out as Offline.

```
<?php if($row['time'] >= 600) { echo "Online"; } else {echo "Offline"; }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $timestamp = strtotime($row['time']);

if($timestamp >= time()-20) { echo "Online"; } else {echo "Offline"; }
?>
```

Note: 20 is in seconds

Comment: Thank you, This would work for a Timestamp as 14141414 example, but i am using by '  2016-04-25 19:13:58  '. Which it doesn't work with a stamp like that. is there any way to make it work with a stamp like that ?

Comment: Thank you, but im affraid this did not work for me :/

Comment: Nevermind, It does work now, Thank you very much my friend!